# Como alinhar uma string em um espaço de 42 caracteres

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou gerando um arquivo de texto e tenho que alinhar o nome da empresa ao centro, mas o nome da empresa irá variar para cada cliente, a quantidade padrão de caracteres são 42.

```
texto="lb_NomeEmpresa.text";
```

desta forma está alinhando a esquerda, simplesmente setando o texto no arquivo.

```
Atualmente:   |NOME EMPRESA           |
Esperado:     |     NOME EMPRESA      |
```

Comment: Você poderia subtrair 42 da quantidade de caracteres do nome da empresa e dividir o resultado por 2, porque aí, você achará quantos espaços deverá colocar no início e final.

Comment: Farei nesta lógica, obrigado emanuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa fazer o que se chama *padding*. Isto até [já existe no .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mas só à esquerda e à direita, você precisa que faça em ambos, então o ideal seria criar um método de extensão para isto.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Write($"|{("Hello World".PadBoth(42))}|");
    }
}

namespace System {
    public static class StringExt {
        public static string PadBoth(this string str, int length, char character = ' ') => str.PadLeft((length - str.Length) / 2 + str.Length, character).PadRight(length, character);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ImhFi0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hMBRcr). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/PadBoth.cs).

Particularmente eu prefiro fazer desta forma. Mas se você tem certeza (dá para ter?) que não vai usar isto outra vez nada impede de utilizar o código *inline* ao invés de criar um método.

O método de extensão você pode colocar em uma biblioteca com uma coleção deles e usar em todas suas aplicações.

Solução baseada [nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17590723/221800).

Comment: Mas assim alinharia a esquerda Bigown e a intensão é que alinhe ao centro dos 42 caracateres.

Comment: Agora que eu vi que a pergunta está toda esquisita por causa da formatação. Vou mudar para fazer o que ele quer.

Comment: Eu tentei simular como está gerando o texto e não foi como esperado, ele tirou os espaços

Comment: @bigown quando copiar o código de algum lugar coloque os créditos. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590528/pad-left-pad-right-pad-center-string

Comment: @TonCunha Não seja apressado, eu não terminei ainda.

Comment: Só pra complementar, no .NetFiddle, os espaços que são adicionados após o nome, não aparecem. Para visualizar melhor, basta trocar o espaço por algum outro caractere.

Comment: @emanuelsn Você está falando da versão antiga.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues tentou agora com esta versão da resposta?

Comment: @bigown vou tentar agora!